# Logging in automatically after logging out

Tags: login, logout

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04. Someplace I've seen a setting to cause the system to log back in after logging out, but I can't find it.  Where is it?  This can be useful for resetting various programs without the cost of a full restart.

Answer (score 1):

It's hiding in Startup and Shutdown/Login Screen/Behavior.  You have to go to a second screen to see it.